Make Trac MasterticketPlugIn Trac1.6 compatible
I'm currently trying to develop your TracMasterTicket plugin so that it can run under Python3 and Trac 1.6. I hope I can ask you a short question about this. In the web_ui.py the ITemplateStreamFilter which is not existing anymore in Trac 1.6 is used. I found some general Infos how to replace the ITemplateStreamFilter but that does not really helps me a lot. Can you maybe give some short advice, how to replace ITemplateStreamFilter in that particular project?
If I just remove the ITemplateSTreamFilter and its Implementation ist is not working anymore (surprisingly)
import functools
import graphviz
import os
import re
import subprocess
import textwrap

from trac.config import BoolOption, ChoiceOption, ListOption, Option
from trac.core import Component, TracError, implements
from trac.mimeview import Mimeview
from trac.resource import ResourceNotFound, get_resource_summary
from trac.ticket.model import Ticket
from trac.ticket.query import Query

from trac.util import as_int, to_unicode
from trac.util.html import html, escape
from trac.util.presentation import classes
from trac.util.translation import _, tag_
from trac.web.api import IRequestFilter, IRequestHandler, ITemplateStreamFilter
from trac.web.chrome import ITemplateProvider, add_ctxtnav, add_script

from model import TicketLinks


class MasterTicketsModule(Component):
    """Provides support for ticket dependencies."""

    implements(IRequestFilter, IRequestHandler, ITemplateProvider, ITemplateStreamFilter)

    dot_path = Option('mastertickets', 'dot_path', default='dot',
        doc="Path to the dot executable.")

    gs_path = Option('mastertickets', 'gs_path', default='gs',
        doc="Path to the ghostscript executable.")

    use_gs = BoolOption('mastertickets', 'use_gs', default=False,
        doc="If enabled, use ghostscript to produce nicer output.")

    acceptable_formats = ListOption('mastertickets', 'acceptable_formats',
        default='svg,png,cmapx', sep=',',
        doc="""The formats that may be chosen. Execute dot -T? for a
            list of options. The first format in the list will be used
            by default. If the list is empty, the png format will be used.
            """)

    closed_color = Option('mastertickets', 'closed_color', default='green',
        doc="Color of closed tickets")

    opened_color = Option('mastertickets', 'opened_color', default='red',
        doc="Color of opened tickets")

    show_key = BoolOption('mastertickets', 'show_key', default=False,
        doc="Show a key for open/closed nodes")

    closed_text = Option('mastertickets', 'closed_text', default='Done',
        doc="Text for key showing closed tickets")

    opened_text = Option('mastertickets', 'opened_text', default='ToDo',
        doc="Text for key showing opened tickets")

    highlight_target = BoolOption('mastertickets', 'highlight_target',
        default=False,
        doc="Highlight target tickets in graph")

    full_graph = BoolOption('mastertickets', 'full_graph', default=False,
        doc="Show full dep. graph, not just direct blocking links")

    graph_direction = ChoiceOption('mastertickets', 'graph_direction',
                                   choices=['TD', 'LR', 'DT', 'RL'],
        doc="""Direction of the dependency graph (TD = Top Down,
            DT = Down Top, LR = Left Right, RL = Right Left).""")

    fields = set(['blocking', 'blockedby'])

    # IRequestFilter methods

    def pre_process_request(self, req, handler):
        return handler

    def post_process_request(self, req, template, data, content_type):
        if template is not None:
            if req.path_info.startswith('/ticket/'):
                # In case of an invalid ticket, the data is invalid
                if not data:
                    return template, data, content_type
                tkt = data['ticket']
                links = TicketLinks(self.env, tkt)

                for i in links.blocked_by:
                    if Ticket(self.env, i)['status'] != 'closed':
                        add_script(req, 'mastertickets/js/disable_resolve.js')
                        break

                # Add link to depgraph if needed.
                if links:
                    add_ctxtnav(req, 'Depgraph',
                                req.href.depgraph('ticket', tkt.id))

                for change in data.get('changes', {}):
                    if 'fields' not in change:
                        continue
                    for field, field_data in change['fields'].iteritems():
                        if field in self.fields:
                            if field_data['new'].strip():
                                new = to_int_set(field_data['new'])
                            else:
                                new = set()
                            if field_data['old'].strip():
                                old = to_int_set(field_data['old'])
                            else:
                                old = set()
                            add = new - old
                            sub = old - new
                            elms = html()
                            if add:
                                elms.append(
                                    html.em(u', '.join(to_unicode(n)
                                                       for n in sorted(add)))
                                )
                                elms.append(u' added')
                            if add and sub:
                                elms.append(u'; ')
                            if sub:
                                elms.append(
                                    html.em(u', '.join(to_unicode(n)
                                                       for n in sorted(sub)))
                                )
                                elms.append(u' removed')
                            field_data['rendered'] = elms

            # Add a link to generate a dependency graph for all the tickets
            # in the milestone
            if req.path_info.startswith('/milestone/'):
                if not data:
                    return template, data, content_type
                milestone = data['milestone']
                add_ctxtnav(req, 'Depgraph',
                            req.href.depgraph('milestone', milestone.name))

        return template, data, content_type

    # ITemplateStreamFilter methods

    def filter_stream(self, req, method, filename, stream, data):
        if not data:
            return stream

        # Try all at the same time to catch changed or processed templates.
        if filename in ['report_view.html', 'query_results.html',
                        'ticket.html', 'query.html']:
            # For ticket.html
            if 'fields' in data and isinstance(data['fields'], list):
                for field in data['fields']:
                    for f in self.fields:
                        if field['name'] == f and data['ticket'][f]:
                            field['rendered'] = \
                                self._link_tickets(req, data['ticket'][f])
            # For query_results.html and query.html
            if 'groups' in data and isinstance(data['groups'], list):
                for group, tickets in data['groups']:
                    for ticket in tickets:
                        for f in self.fields:
                            if f in ticket:
                                ticket[f] = self._link_tickets(req, ticket[f])
            # For report_view.html
            if 'row_groups' in data and isinstance(data['row_groups'], list):
                for group, rows in data['row_groups']:
                    for row in rows:
                        if 'cell_groups' in row and \
                                isinstance(row['cell_groups'], list):
                            for cells in row['cell_groups']:
                                for cell in cells:
                                    # If the user names column in the report
                                    # differently (blockedby AS "blocked by")
                                    # then this will not find it
                                    if cell.get('header', {}).get('col') \
                                            in self.fields:
                                        cell['value'] = \
                                            self._link_tickets(req,
                                                               cell['value'])
        return stream

    # ITemplateProvider methods

    def get_htdocs_dirs(self):
        from pkg_resources import resource_filename
        return [('mastertickets', resource_filename(__name__, 'htdocs'))]

    def get_templates_dirs(self):
        from pkg_resources import resource_filename
        return [resource_filename(__name__, 'templates')]

    # IRequestHandler methods

    def match_request(self, req):
        match = re.match(r'^/depgraph/(?P<realm>ticket|milestone)/'
                         r'(?P<id>((?!depgraph).)+)(/depgraph)?$',
                         req.path_info)
        if match:
            req.args['realm'] = match.group('realm')
            req.args['id'] = match.group('id')
            return True

    def process_request(self, req):
        req.perm.require('TICKET_VIEW')
        realm = req.args['realm']
        id_ = req.args['id']

        if not which(self.dot_path):
            raise TracError(_("Path to dot executable is invalid: %(path)s",
                              path=self.dot_path))

        # Urls to generate the depgraph for a ticket is /depgraph/ticketnum
        # Urls to generate the depgraph for a milestone is
        # /depgraph/milestone/milestone_name

        # List of tickets to generate the depgraph.
        if realm == 'milestone':
            # We need to query the list of tickets in the milestone
            query = Query(self.env, constraints={'milestone': [id_]}, max=0)
            tkt_ids = [fields['id'] for fields in query.execute(req)]
        else:
            tid = as_int(id_, None)
            if tid is None:
                raise TracError(tag_("%(id)s is not a valid ticket id.",
                                     id=html.tt(id_)))
            tkt_ids = [tid]

        # The summary argument defines whether we place the ticket id or
        # its summary in the node's label
        label_summary = 0
        if 'summary' in req.args:
            label_summary = int(req.args.get('summary'))

        g = self._build_graph(req, tkt_ids, label_summary=label_summary)
        if req.path_info.endswith('/depgraph') or 'format' in req.args:
            format_ = req.args.get('format')
            if format_ == 'text':
                # In case g.__str__ returns unicode, convert it in ascii
                req.send(to_unicode(g).encode('ascii', 'replace'),
                         'text/plain')
            elif format_ == 'debug':
                import pprint
                req.send(
                    pprint.pformat(
                        [TicketLinks(self.env, tkt_id) for tkt_id in tkt_ids]
                    ),
                    'text/plain')
            elif format_ is not None:
                if format_ in self.acceptable_formats:
                    mimetype = Mimeview(self.env). \
                               mime_map.get(format_, 'text/plain')
                    req.send(g.render(self.dot_path, format_), mimetype)
                else:
                    raise TracError(_("The %(format)s format is not allowed.",
                                      format=format_))

            if self.use_gs:
                ps = g.render(self.dot_path, 'ps2')
                gs = subprocess.Popen(
                    [self.gs_path, '-q', '-dTextAlphaBits=4',
                     '-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4', '-sDEVICE=png16m',
                     '-sOutputFile=%stdout%', '-'],
                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
                img, err = gs.communicate(ps)
                if err:
                    self.log.debug('MasterTickets: Error from gs: %s', err)
            else:
                img = g.render(self.dot_path)
            req.send(img, 'image/png')
        else:
            data = {}

            # Add a context link to enable/disable labels in nodes.
            if label_summary:
                add_ctxtnav(req, 'Without labels',
                            req.href(req.path_info, summary=0))
            else:
                add_ctxtnav(req, 'With labels',
                            req.href(req.path_info, summary=1))

            if realm == 'milestone':
                add_ctxtnav(req, 'Back to Milestone: %s' % id_,
                            req.href.milestone(id_))
                data['milestone'] = id_
            else:
                data['ticket'] = id_
                add_ctxtnav(req, 'Back to Ticket #%s' % id_,
                            req.href.ticket(id_))
            try:
                data['format'] = self.acceptable_formats[0]
            except IndexError:
                data['format'] = 'png'
            data['graph'] = g
            data['graph_render'] = functools.partial(g.render, self.dot_path)
            data['use_gs'] = self.use_gs

            return 'depgraph.html', data, None

    def _build_graph(self, req, tkt_ids, label_summary=0):
        g = graphviz.Graph(log=self.log)
        g.label_summary = label_summary

        g.attributes['rankdir'] = self.graph_direction

        node_default = g['node']
        node_default['style'] = 'filled'

        edge_default = g['edge']
        edge_default['style'] = ''

        # Force this to the top of the graph
        for tid in tkt_ids:
            g[tid]

        if self.show_key:
            g[-1]['label'] = self.closed_text
            g[-1]['fillcolor'] = self.closed_color
            g[-1]['shape'] = 'box'
            g[-2]['label'] = self.opened_text
            g[-2]['fillcolor'] = self.opened_color
            g[-2]['shape'] = 'box'

        links = TicketLinks.walk_tickets(self.env, tkt_ids, self.full_graph)
        links = sorted(links, key=lambda link: link.tkt.id)
        for link in links:
            tkt = link.tkt
            node = g[tkt.id]
            if label_summary:
                label = u'#%s %s' % (tkt.id, tkt['summary'])
            else:
                label = u'#%s' % tkt.id
            node['label'] = escape('\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(label, 30)))
            node['fillcolor'] = tkt['status'] == 'closed' and \
                                self.closed_color or self.opened_color
            node['URL'] = req.href.ticket(tkt.id)
            node['alt'] = u'Ticket #%s' % tkt.id
            node['tooltip'] = escape('#%s (%s) %s' % (tkt.id, tkt['status'],
                                                      tkt['summary']))
            if self.highlight_target and tkt.id in tkt_ids:
                node['penwidth'] = 3

            for n in link.blocking:
                node > g[n]

        return g

    def _link_tickets(self, req, tickets):
        items = []

        for i, word in enumerate(re.split(r'([;,\s]+)', tickets)):
            if i % 2:
                items.append(word)
            elif word:
                tid = word
                word = '#%s' % word

                try:
                    ticket = Ticket(self.env, tid)
                    if 'TICKET_VIEW' in req.perm(ticket.resource):
                        word = \
                            html.a(
                                '#%s' % ticket.id,
                                href=req.href.ticket(ticket.id),
                                class_=classes(ticket['status'], 'ticket'),
                                title=get_resource_summary(self.env,
                                                           ticket.resource)
                            )
                except ResourceNotFound:
                    pass

                items.append(word)

        if items:
            return html(items)
        else:
            return None


def to_int_set(splittable):
    return set(int(n) for n in re.split(r'[\s,]+', splittable))


def which(program):

    def is_exe(fpath):
        return os.path.isfile(fpath) and os.access(fpath, os.X_OK)

    fpath, fname = os.path.split(program)
    if fpath:
        if is_exe(program):
            return program
    else:
        for path in os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep):
            path = path.strip('"')
            exe_file = os.path.join(path, program)
            if is_exe(exe_file):
                return exe_file

    return None

Best regards
Paul
